# Conditional filtering with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Suppose, I am given the datasets **AB** (25x2), and **ABC** (30x3) respectively. How could I filter the data in **ABC** based on both variables ***a*** and ***b*** of the dataset **AB** simultaneously, which would result in **ABC_filtered**? The variable ***n*** in **ABC_filtered** gives the total number of instances where the dataset **ABC** meets the filtering criteria for the variables ***a*** (should belong to AB$a) and ***b*** (should belong to AB$b within the subset of AB$a values) simultaneously. For example, an instance is only counted if both:

```
a=A AND b=c(1,2,3,4,5) # NOT PART OF CODE
a=B AND b=c(6,7,8,9,10) # NOT PART OF CODE
a=C AND b=c(11,12,13,14,15) # NOT PART OF CODE
a=D AND b=c(16,17,18,19,20) # NOT PART OF CODE
a=E AND b=c(21,22,23,24,25) # NOT PART OF CODE

AB <- data.frame(a=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), each=5), b=seq(1:25))
ABC <- structure(list(s = c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
                            "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", 
                            "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
                            "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
                            "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3"), 
                      a = c("D", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "C", 
                            "C", "F", "E", "G", "G", "C", "G", 
                            "A", "C", "F", "H", "G", "B", "C", 
                            "G", "C", "F", "A", "G", "E", "G", 
                            "B", "D"), 
                      b = c(3L, 24L, 8L, 23L, 9L, 17L, 14L, 2L, 
                            1L, 2L, 1L, 23L, 19L, 25L, 15L, 19L, 
                            5L, 21L, 13L, 6L, 18L, 23L, 7L, 23L, 
                            17L, 23L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 18L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
ABC_filtered <- data.frame(s=c("s1","s2","s3","s3"), 
                           a=c("C","B","B","D"), n=c(1,1,1,1))
```

My attempt at creating the filter did not work as expected.

```
library(magrittr)
ABC %>% 
  group_by(s, a, b) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(all(
    a %in% AB$a, b %in% AB$b[AB$a])) %>% 
  count() # DID NOT WORK
```

Could someone help me code this correctly? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `AB$b[AB$a]` returns all `NA`'s, since `AB$a` does not index `AB$b`. In the first pipe, try `b %in% AB$b` instead and see if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `semi_join()` followed by `count()` from `dplyr`. `semi_join()` acts as a filtering join using `AB` to "filter" `ABC`, and `count()` does the aggregation.

```r
AB <- data.frame(a=rep(c("A","B","C","D","E"), each=5), b=seq(1:25))
ABC <- structure(list(s = c("s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", 
                            "s1", "s1", "s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", 
                            "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", "s2", 
                            "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", 
                            "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3", "s3"), 
                      a = c("D", "H", "H", "F", "F", "H", "C", 
                            "C", "F", "E", "G", "G", "C", "G", 
                            "A", "C", "F", "H", "G", "B", "C", 
                            "G", "C", "F", "A", "G", "E", "G", 
                            "B", "D"), 
                      b = c(3L, 24L, 8L, 23L, 9L, 17L, 14L, 2L, 
                            1L, 2L, 1L, 23L, 19L, 25L, 15L, 19L, 
                            5L, 21L, 13L, 6L, 18L, 23L, 7L, 23L, 
                            17L, 23L, 14L, 15L, 6L, 18L)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
ABC_filtered <- data.frame(s=c("s1","s2","s3","s3"), 
                           a=c("C","B","B","D"), n=c(1,1,1,1))

library(dplyr)
semi_join(x = ABC, y = AB, by = c("a", "b")) %>%
  count(s, a)
#>    s a n
#> 1 s1 C 1
#> 2 s2 B 1
#> 3 s3 B 1
#> 4 s3 D 1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Brilliant idea, @Wil! It definitely does the trick.

Answer (score -1):

I tried

```
ABC_answer <- merge(AB, ABC, all.x = TRUE) %>% tidyr::drop_na()
```

and got this result:
[image]

Comment: Not sure where the 1's came from in the ABC_filtered though...

Comment: @JamesRisner I don't have a solution yet. I am looking for help.

Comment: @Andrew Lee I gave your solution a try but it did not fix my issue.